# Settings not saved in Settins.settings

Tags: c#, settings

I'm using Settings.Settings to store settings at run-time. It was very helpful for my earlier application to store data. But in my current project its not saving the settings data. My application have some tab and each tab contains some TextBox. Im using textBox Text to store string values.

`Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1 = textBox2.Text;

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

It is a working method for  my all previous application.But I can't understand why its not working in my current project.

Comment: It was working before, and "suddenly" stoped worked? Can you provide more information?

Comment: It worked in my previous applications. In my current project its not working

Comment: Can you provide more information about your current project? This two lines of code seem correct, from this MSDN post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx Do you have write permissions in user’s local hidden application data? "User settings are saved in a file within a subfolder of the user’s local hidden application data folder."

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not include many details, I've tried to answer as much as possible:

Try to perform a [Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx) and then saved settings get loaded. 
You have to call the Upgrade method of ApplicationSettingsBase derived class (that is normally called Settings and is created for you by Visual Studio)

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
```

When/where to call the `Upgrade` method? There is a simple trick you can apply: define a user setting called `UpgradeRequired` (example) as `bool` (the easiest way is through IDE). Make sure its default value is `true`.

Insert this code snipped at the start of the application:

```
  if (Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
  {
      Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
      Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
      Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
  }
```

So the Upgrade method will be called only after the version changes and only one time (since you disable further upgrades by setting UpgradeRequired = false until a version change - when the property regains default value of true).

Check the scope of your settings [USER/APPLICATION]
Try this out, and if it doesn't work check the below conditions.

Also, a more detailed question next time would be much appreciated.

Permission (NTFS permission)

Or Active directory permission

Or capacity of windows drive is full.

Or there exist two or more user folders and you checked another.

For example: There are two or three folders, user.domain, user.workgroupname, user.

Despite all this, I suggest you to learn about `System.Reflection` and develop your personalized method to save settings, the option provided by the Visual Studio isn't very dependable.

Hope this was helpful.